`ip -j route show` output json schema
The ip -j -p route show shows routes in JSON format, but I can't find the JSON schema or equivalent scheme (e.g. typescript or serde) anywhere. Is there a predefined schema for the JSON output of ip route?
I found node-iproute but the schema is not correct. (some fields are missing e.g. pref, and some of the required/optional fields are incorrect e.g. protocol is not required)
example output:
[
    {
        "dst": "default",
        "gateway": "192.168.100.1",
        "dev": "enp4s0",
        "protocol": "dhcp",
        "metric": 100,
        "flags": [ ]
    },
    {
        "dst": "192.168.100.0/24",
        "dev": "enp4s0",
        "protocol": "kernel",
        "scope": "link",
        "prefsrc": "192.168.100.126",
        "metric": 100,
        "flags": [ ]
    }
]

For example, what are the possible values of the dst field? It can be default and IP range. Can it be other values? What about other fields?

While it would be very useful to have such a schema I guess that you unfortunately have to consult the man page of ip-route and investigate option-by-option what are the allowed parameters ... (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-route.8.html)
